# Mass add attribute to all data extensions

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, ssjs

I am trying to add a created date attribute to all of the data extensions that we have in our internal Marketing Cloud BU. We have about 1000+ and I was wondering if there is a way to accomplish this? We are trying to update all historical but I haven't really seen anything that shows a way to do this. Has anyone tried to do this before?

Answer (score 1):

You should use SOAP/WSProxy to list all your data extensions, first by using a retrieve request with this structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
     <soapenv:Header>
        <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
           <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-32259181" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
              <wsse:Username>user</wsse:Username>
              <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">password</wsse:Password>
           </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
     </soapenv:Header>
     <soapenv:Body>
        <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
           <RetrieveRequest>
              <ObjectType>DataExtension</ObjectType>
              <Properties>CustomerKey</Properties>
              <Properties>Name</Properties>
              <Properties>CategoryID</Properties>
           </RetrieveRequest>
        </RetrieveRequestMsg>
     </soapenv:Body>
  </soapenv:Envelope>
```

When you have all of your names/external keys of data extensions, you can iterate through them, adding a new column to each of them respectively, following this sample request example:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-5501096" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
                <wsse:Username>XXX</wsse:Username> 
                <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">XXX</wsse:Password> 
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <UpdateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <Options /> 
            <Objects xsi:type="ns1:DataExtension" xmlns:ns1="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
                <CustomerKey>8533EC32-5E12-4599-B279-0369EFCB38E3</CustomerKey> 
                <Fields>
                    <Field>
                        <Name>New Field</Name> 
                        <MaxLength>200</MaxLength> 
                        <IsRequired>true</IsRequired> 
                    </Field>
                </Fields>
            </Objects>
        </UpdateRequest>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I would suggest using [WSProxy](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_WSProxy_useSSJS.htm), basically allowing you to use SOAP request in your Script activities in automation studio, making the operation easier, as you can e.g. add all the external keys of data extensions to an array in SSJS.